# Good front-end solution for displaying live commercial network schema

Tags: frontend, diagram

We've a net of vending machines of a few types and we have common API to rule them and get data from our vendors. The aim is to show live graphical schema for this net in a browser. The schema should include icons of machines, centers, servers etc. and the lines, connecting the objects with each other.

It's evident that the topography is flexible. We can set up new machines, change bindings, etc. Thus the schema should be traced automatically: I wish to give it some objects and relations as an array or JS object and see a graphical schema in the browser.

All the object should be clickable. I wish to click to the vendor icon and get statistics for it.

And last but not the least, this should work real-time. An operator should monitor this live schema, and, if trouble occurs, take some actions.

Back-end doesn't cause problems. I can do a DB and push all business-logic to server-side. But I wonder, is there a perfect way to display such stuff at front-end? Is there a ready-made solution for such kind of diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think a ready-made solution of such a specific set of requirements exists (but I could easily be wrong on that). You could however take a look at [D3](http://d3js.org/). D3 is a Javascript 'data-driven' library to create dynamic charts and graphs. Maybe you can find something useful for your use case, as the library is quite flexible and offers many features.